# Write padding bytes ('0') with a function that takes a pointer and a length as arguments

Tags: c++

I have a Stream object with a `Write(const void *P, size_t size)` function.
I want to call it to write n Bytes of `'0'`. How would I do that without having to initialize a dummy `unsigend char` array with `0` and handing a pointer to the `Write()` function?

Comment: Obviously you cannot. That is a deficiency of the interface of `Write`, and the only solution is to add another overload better suited to the task.

Comment: The easiest solution is to call the Write() function X times in a loop, but I would prefer the dummy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do that by calling some other function than `Write()`, which obviously does not handle your requirements.